# Pandas Dataframe, average non 0 value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have the following Pandas Dataframe 'df':

```
a1  a2  a3  b1
0   0   0   1
1   2   0   2
3   0   0   3
2   4   0   4
```

How do I get the average value of "a" for from a1, a2, a3, ignoring the 0 value?

```
a1  a2  a3  b1  avg(a)
0   0   0   1   0
1   2   0   2   1.5
3   0   0   3   3.0
2   4   0   4   3.0
```

I'm stuck with manual approach where I convert the value > 0 to 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) the `a` like columns, then [`.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the zeros in these columns and take [`.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) along `axis=1`:

```
a = df.filter(like='a')
df['avg'] = a.mask(a.eq(0)).mean(1).fillna(0)

# OR df['avg'] = a[a > 0].mean(1).fillna(0)
```

---

```
   a1  a2  a3  b1  avg
0   0   0   0   1  0.0
1   1   2   0   2  1.5
2   3   0   0   3  3.0
3   2   4   0   4  3.0
```

Comment: thanks, this works
now if i had a lot of averaging, for example a1 a2 a3, b1 b2 b3
i just need to make variable for those column

Comment: @ngakanalit Can you please elaborate? Do you need to average all the `a's` column then all the b's columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a1': [0, 1, 3, 2],
                   'a2': [0, 2, 0, 4],
                   'a3': [0, 0, 0, 0],
                   'b1': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

# remove the last column
df1 = df.drop('b1', 1)

# counting non-zeros
df2 = df1.astype(bool).sum(axis=1)

# sum and divide
df3 = df1.sum(axis=1) / df2
df['avg(a)'] = df3.fillna(0)
print(df)


   a1  a2  a3  b1  avg(a)
0   0   0   0   1     0.0
1   1   2   0   2     1.5
2   3   0   0   3     3.0
3   2   4   0   4     3.0
```

Comment: in some cases this approach will be handy, but the solution above is much simpler,
thanks